# HTML table to Drupal table

Tags: javascript, theming

How can I translate this to drupal table?

http://www.bootply.com/sXmuAJQjO4

I know how to do simple tables and the header and first row I can do also with this code:

```
$title = '<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading"><h3>Table Title</h3></div>
<div class="panel-body">';

    $header = array(
        array('data' => '&nbsp;'),
        array('data' => 'Job Name'),
        array('data' => 'Description'),
        array('data' => 'Provider Name'),
        array('data' => 'Region',),
        array('data' => 'Status'),
    );

    #'data-toggle' => 'collapse'
    $row = array(
        'data' => array(
            array('data' => '<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></button>'),
            array('data' => 'OBS Name',),
            array('data' => 'OBS Description'),
            array('data' => 'hpcloud'),
            array('data' => 'nova'),
            array('data' => 'created'),
        ),
        'class' => array('accordion-toggle'),
        'data-toggle' => 'collapse',
        'data-target' => '#demo1',
    );
    $rows[] = $row;
```

But I can't add the hidden row. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the hidden row, you need a second table which would look like:

```
// This is the hidden table
$table_hidden = '<div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1">';
$table_hidden .= theme('table', array('header' => $header_hidden, 'rows' => $rows_hidden));
$table_hidden .= '</div>';

$row2 = array(
  'data' => array(
    array(
      'data' => $table_hidden,
      'colspan' => '12',
      'class' => array('hiddenRow'),
    ),
    array('data' => 'OBS Name',),
  // more array data here
);
```

Option 2, a more module-clean way would be to use hook_theme function and create a simple template file where additional markup is placed like so.

```
function YOURMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'any_name_you_like' => array(
      'template' => 'hiddentable', // This called hiddentable.tpl.php
      'arguments' => array('table' => null),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then in your page callback or wherever, you would just need to use your declared theme function like so.

```
$table_hidden = theme('table', array('header' => $header_hidden, 'rows' => $rows_hidden));

$row2 = array(
  'data' => array(
    array(
      'data' => theme('any_name_you_like', array('table' => $table_hidden)),
      'colspan' => '12',
      'class' => array('hiddenRow'),
    ),
    array('data' => 'OBS Name',),
  // more array data here
);
```

Now in your hiddentable.tpl.php

```
<div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1">
  <?php print $variables['table']; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Leolando Tan. I thought that the first variable you define (the one with the div) could be made in a more drupal way. That was my problem. If it's ok to do it like this or if it's meant to be like this, fine for me :)

Comment: Oh! My bad! I edited my post to add a second option. Please take a look and if it satisfies your need give it an up vote. Thanks! :)

Comment: You're very welcome! Glad to help! :)